# C# Distinct with ability to choose which object to save, which ones to remove

Tags: c#

I implemented this comparer which works OK.

```
class ReservationDatesDistinctComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReservationModel>
{
    public bool Equals(ReservationModel x, ReservationModel y)
    {
        return x.FromDate.Date== y.FromDate.Date && x.ToDate.Date == y.ToDate.Date && x.UnitId == x.UnitId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ReservationModel product)
    {  
        int hashProductCode = 1;
        return  hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

But on `ReservationModel` I have some other property let's call it `ReservationType` and I would like to filter out with distinct same dates but keep only `ReservationModel` who has Type A not Type B.

How it is posible to affect on `Distinct` which model it will choose?

Comment: Side note: `GetHashCode` is the *worst* correct implementation.

Comment: No, because I need type A, and type B , but only when I have type A and type B which both have same dates, I only need that reservation with those dates which type is A.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider please read my comment above.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with GetHashCode if I don't care about it?

Comment: A custom Equals() method can have more the two parameters so you can add other properties as parameters to the method.

Comment: If a.Equals(b) == true, a.GetHashCode() should also be the same as b.GetHashCode().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct` will keep the elements it encounters first, a possible solution would be to order those which have `ReservationType` `A` first:

```
reservatonModels.OrderByDescending(m => m.ReservationType == ReservationType.A)
    .Distinct(new ReservationDatesDistinctComparer());
```

Comment: _"Distinct will keep the elements it encounters first"_ - is it documented as such, or is it just that the current implementation happens to do so, and it _might_ change in the future, or different implementations of the BCL might do it differently already?  The only thing I can see in the docs vaguely related is that it _"returns an unordered sequence"_, which to me means it doesn't pay much attention to ordering of elements and could easily change.

Comment: This behaviour relies on an undocumented implementation detail of `Distinct`. (Having said that, the behaviour is unlikely to change.)

Comment: It is not documented as such however as the asker explicitly wants a solution which works with `Distinct`, this is the only solution I can think of being possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `Distinct` for this. (Unless you want to rely on undocumented implementation details, as per Lukazoid's answer.)

Something similar to this might do the trick. (Group the elements that your comparer deems to be equal, then order each group so that Type A is prioritised, then take the first element from each group.)

```
var result = source.GroupBy(x => x, new ReservationDatesDistinctComparer())
                   .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => (x.ReservationType == "Type A") ? 1 : 2)
                                 .First());
```